# Do I need to validate a subscale I made in SPSS from a previously validated scale?

Tags: validation, scales

I am using a commonly used, validated scale on positive and negative affect. If I want to look at the effect of the negative items in isolation, does the subscale I make of the negative items need to be validated again? If so, how do I do this please? I can only find information on full scale development and validation, and nothing on how to validate a subscale of a previously validated scale.
I have an additional question please - can I use a premade subscale from another validated scale in isolation?
Thanks